# Additional space when zooming on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, responsive-design

I am experiencing problem with white-space which appears after I double click on some of my website elements when I am using IPhone.
[Soulika](https://soulikadevst.z6.web.core.windows.net/) here you can try it on your own if you access from IPhone and zoom with double click you will have white-space which follows you along with further movements.
Mostly happends when I am zooming footer part, but actually might happen everywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I were able to find the problem and soultion.

Problem:

- I have hidded html tag scrollbar and moved it to one of my inner containers inside DefaultLayout;
- This work complitely fine before we start to talk about IPhone cross-browser compatability.
- Once I try to zoom my content inside content container it propagetes zoom event to parent component, but from some reason instead of stoping at the point of my DefaultLayout wrapper - element which has overflow activated and height defined in px( mandatory in order to configure overlow ) it propagetes up to window and zooms window itself.

Solution: I have changed the approach and moved the overflow back to html which is now pretty much content element and window is a wrapper with predifined height. Now everything works complitely fine as zooming accessing my content and do not propagets to parent.

[image: how to get window and html height]